# Get vertical space in table that table lines are not covered by image

Tags: tables, longtable

The table I created looks as following:

[image]

How can I get some horizontal space between the picture and the top of the cell such that not half of the line is covered by the picture?

This is my code:

```
\begin{longtable}{| p{.1\textwidth} | p{.15\textwidth} | p{.65\textwidth} | }
\hline
\textbf{Kanton} & \textbf{Umsetzung Wissen} & \textbf{Umsetzung Können} \\ \hline 

\centering AG & \centering 0.80  & \centering $\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.68\textwidth]{resultate/AG.png}}}$\\ \hline

\centering AI & \centering 0.80 & \raisebox{-\totalheight}$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=0.68\textwidth]{resultate/AI.png}}}$\\ \hline
\caption{Umsetzung des Anhangs zum Rahmenlehrplan} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable}
```

Comment: Please, always try so show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) instead of a code snippet that uses external files, we do not have.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `m`-columns to not need `\raisebox` and `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\section*{Klötzchengrafik}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\Centering}m{.1\textwidth}|>{\Centering}m{.15\textwidth}
  |>{\Centering}m{.65\textwidth}| }
\hline
  \textbf{Kanton} & \textbf{Umsetzung Wissen} & \textbf{Umsetzung Können} \\ 
  \hline
   AG & 0.80  & \vskip-1.2ex\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
  \hline
  AI & 0.80 & \vskip-1.2ex\includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\
  \hline
\caption{Umsetzung des Anhangs zum Rahmenlehrplan}% needs to go inside
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}\\
\end{longtable}

\clearpage
\section*{Tabelle:}

\begin{longtable}{>{\Centering}m{.1\textwidth}>{\Centering}m{.15\textwidth}
  >{\Centering}m{.65\textwidth} }
\caption{Umsetzung des Anhangs zum Rahmenlehrplan}% needs to go inside
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}\\
% longtable environment
  \toprule
  \textbf{Kanton} & \textbf{Umsetzung Wissen} & \textbf{Umsetzung Können} \\ 
  \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \caption[]{Umsetzung des Anhangs zum Rahmenlehrplan (Fortsetzung)}\\
  \toprule
  \textbf{Kanton} & \textbf{Umsetzung Wissen} & \textbf{Umsetzung Können} \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \bottomrule
  \endfoot
  AG & 0.80  & \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-a}\\
  \addlinespace
  AI & 0.80 & \includegraphics[width=0.65\textwidth]{example-image-b}\\
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]